# Unable to remove Value from Array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, data-manipulation

i have following array

```
var userIdArray=["1", "3", "6", "39", "62", "139"];
```

i want to remove array value using value

i have tried following method

```
function  deleteMember(id) {
                alert(id+"="+userIdArray.indexOf(id));

                userIdArray.splice(userIdArray.indexOf(id),1);

            }
```

But it always remove last value.

Also noticed that `userIdArray.indexOf(id)` always return -1 but if pass value like `userIdArray.indexOf("6")` then it will delete particular position
Can any one help me how to remove particular value ?

Comment: you function works fine. what is the problem with it?

Comment: if id=6 i pass then it will delete last value not that value

Comment: you need to take a string as value, not just a number, because indexOf looks for same type and value (strict).

Comment: @NinaScholz.ya kyon posted answer.thanks so much

Comment: maybe you think a bit about the data and keep same types, both with the array and with seaching for an index. a type casting is not advisable, because you loos in the overview. as result, i suggest to use the same type for seraching without converting to another type or using weak comparions.

Comment: @NinaScholz.thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got a problem that your id that you are putting into the `deleteMember` functions isn't a String.

This could probably solve your problem:

```js
var userIdArray=["1", "3", "6", "39", "62", "139"];

function  deleteMember(id) {
    removeId = String(id)
    removeIndex = userIdArray.indexOf(removeId)
    if(removeIndex != -1)
     userIdArray.splice(removeIndex,1);
}

deleteMember(3)
console.log(userIdArray)
```

**A more beautiful way would be handling your data like this: (ES6 approach)**

```js
var userIdArray=["1", "3", "6", "39", "62", "139"];

deleteMemberFromArray = (array, value) => 
    array.filter((member) => 
      member != String(value)
    );


userIdArray = deleteMemberFromArray(userIdArray, 3)
console.log(userIdArray)
```

Comment: Thanks Kyon.its working fine.silly mistake .i  tried using to string but not this before .thanks

Comment: Just secured some things up, give that edited one another shot.

Comment: feel also free to mark this as your solution, if you haven't got any further questions regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

> [jQuery.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

You can use in `return ( i > 10 );`  any condition and calculate to get

```js
var arr = [ 1, 9, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1 ];

 
arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function( n, i ) {
  return ( i > 10 );
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Farhad for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use `filter()`:

```js
var userIdArray = ["1", "3", "6", "39", "62", "139"];
function deleteMember(id) {
  userIdArray = userIdArray.filter(i => i != id);
}

deleteMember('3');

console.log(userIdArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this much shorter and simpler way to achieve what you're looking for:

```
function deleteMember(id) {
    alert(id+"="+userIdArray.indexOf(id));
    array.splice(i, 1);
}
```